# I cannot add categories to the site REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { connect } from "react-redux";

import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

import * as categoryActions from '../../redux/actions/categoryActions';

import { ListGroup, ListGroupItem } from 'reactstrap';

import {Badge} from 'reactstrap';

class CategoryList extends Component{

componentDidMount(){

this.props.actions.getCategories()

}

selectCategory=(category)=>{

this.props.changeCategory(category)

}

render(){

return(

#### categories

{this.props.categories.map(category =>(

<ListGroupItem active = {category.id===this.props.currentCategory.id}

onClick={()=> this.selectCategory(category)} key={category.id}>

{category.categoryName}

))}

);

}

}

function mapStateToProps(state){

return {

currentCategory:state.changeCategoryReducer,

categories:state.CategoryListReducer

}

}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){

return{

actions:{

getCategories:bindActionCreators(categoryActions.getCategories,dispatch),

changeCategory:bindActionCreators(categoryActions.changeCategory,dispatch),

}

};

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryList)

Comment: Add details to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

cartSummary
import {
UncontrolledDropdown,
DropdownToggle,
DropdownMenu,
DropdownItem,
NavItem,
NavLink,
Badge
} from 'reactstrap';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as cartActions from '../../redux/actions/cartActions';
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
class CartSummary extends Component {
renderEmpty() {
return (

setiniz bos

)
}
renderSummary() {
return (


sepetiniz

```
                <DropdownMenu right>
                    {
                        this.props.cart.map(cartItem => (

                            <DropdownItem key={cartItem.product.id}>
                                 <Badge color ="danger" onClick={()=>this.props.actions.removeFromCart(cartItem.product)}> x </Badge>
                                {cartItem.product.productName}

                            <Badge color ="success"> {cartItem.quantity} </Badge>
                            </DropdownItem>
                        ))
                    }
                    <DropdownItem divider />
                    <DropdownItem>
                        sepete git
              </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div >
                {
                    this.props.cart.length > 0 ? this.renderSummary() : this.renderEmpty()
                }

            </div>
        )
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        cart: state.cartReducer
    }
}
    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
        return {
            actions:{
                removeFromCart:
                bindActionCreators(
                    cartActions.removeFromCart,
                    dispatch)
            }

        }
    }
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(CartSummary)
```